# Tailwind CSS not applying using CLI

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to use tailwind css in my project, seems like only font changes but there's no effect on using the classes.

im using live server extension on vs code.

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "testing",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npx tailwindcss -i tailwind.css -o ./public/styles.css"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.9"
  }
}
```

tailwind.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    '*'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

tailwind.css

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="w-full bg-purple-900">
        <h1 class="text-green-100">
            <div class="bg-pink-500">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat quidem voluptas facilis expedita sequi molestiae mollitia nobis doloremque tempora, suscipit illo voluptatum, totam ex maiores! Quaerat fugit laborum incidunt voluptate!</p>
            </div>
        </h1>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

so if i comment out the linking of styles.css, i don't see any effect.
and as soon as i use styles.css, the font changes which reflects that tailwind is working
but if i apply the classes, it doesn't work at all.

Steps i followed:

1. created package.json using `npm init -y`
2. installed tailwind cli `npm install -D tailwindcss`
3. created tailwind.config.js file (root folder)
4. created tailwind.css file and added tailwind directives in that file (root folder)
5. added a public folder in which index.html and styles.css file are there
6. for building the styles.css file, `npx tailwindcss -i tailwind.css -o ./public/styles.css` is used.
7. styles.css file now contains some css of ~400 lines of code
8. linked styles.css file in index.html

Comment: did you run the `npm run dev` , also check your generated css file what's in there ?

Comment: yes i did run that command, also there's indeed some css written in styles.css (generated file)

Comment: then check if you included the right file path and also check if it is really effecting, by inspecting elements

Comment: i've double checked the path, it is correct. i still dont know where is the problem.
for reference, i've added "steps that i've followed" in the ques

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> yes i did run that command, also there's indeed some css written in styles.css (generated file)

This is the default CSS reset that ships with tailwind by default.

### back to the problem

For me the dev command worked, when I changed the tailwind config file to following:

```js
module.exports = {
    content: [
        './public/*'
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
}
```

I ensured with this, that tailwind is looking up the classes that have to be used from all files in the `public` directory (the `tailwind.css` file gets included in the npm command).

I would also recommend to take a look into the [official documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation), there you can find more examples of how to use/customize the `content` configuration.

Answer (score 0):

add here in ts.config.json

```
 './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
```

work with nextjs 13

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).